# @KafkaListener Graceful Shutdown with Batch Kakfa listener not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

2020-05-14 19:32:11.238  INFO 19880 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483547 within timeout of 30000: [org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry]

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring requires beans in each `SmartLifecycle` phase to stop within 30 seconds; you can alter that behavior by adding the following bean:

```java
@Bean
public DefaultLifecycleProcessor lifecycleProcessor() {
    DefaultLifecycleProcessor lp = new DefaultLifecycleProcessor();
    lp.setTimeoutPerShutdownPhase(120_000);
    return lp;
}
```

**EDIT**

Stopping the container while its listener is processing a batch won't affect the processing of the batch; the listener thread is not killed by the container; the container will, however, publish a container stopped event after 10 seconds by default (container property `shutDownTimeout`) even if the listener hasn't actually finished.

If you are worried about the lifecycle processor killing the thread mid-batch and don't want to increase its timeout, you can perform the graceful shutdown with a combination of pausing the consumer and listening for events.

Here is an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So61799727Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61799727Application.class, args);
    }


    @KafkaListener(id = "so61799727", topics = "so61799727", concurrency = "3")
    public void listen(List<String> in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so61799727").partitions(3).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template,
            KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {

        return args -> {
            sendTen(template);
            System.out.println("Hit enter to pause container");
            System.in.read();
            registry.getListenerContainer("so61799727").pause();
        };
    }

    public static void sendTen(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> template.send("so61799727", "foo" + i));
    }

}
```

```java
@Component
class Eventer {

    privaate final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    private final AtomicInteger paused = new AtomicInteger();

    Eventer(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void paused(ConsumerPausedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        if (this.paused.incrementAndGet() ==
                event.getContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class).getConcurrency()) {
            System.out.println("All containers paused");
            So61799727Application.sendTen(this.template);
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void idle(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.listener.idle-event-interval=5000
spring.kafka.listener.type=batch
spring.kafka.producer.properties.linger.ms=50
```

Comment: is there any way to that i can know that consumer instances are running i.e. batch is still processing the messages?? 
or
do not stop ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer until messages in batch acknowledged properly i.e. all in batch are consumed ???

Comment: when i shutdown the application, ListenerContainer stopped properly i.e i can see the status as stopped using KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.
but messages in batch aren't processed.

so i am looking for a way to verify all the messages in batch consumed.

Comment: Stopping the container will not affect the listener processing the current batch; the container doesn't kill the listener thread. The lifecycle processor is different, however. See the edit to my answer for more details and a technique you can use for graceful shutdown.

Comment: thank you sir.
but is there any other way i.e. EventListener to know consumer is stopping and batch is in middle of processing the messages ???

Comment: That would be the responsibility of your listener - set a flag at the beginning and reset it when you are done. The container only emits events when it has control over what the thread is doing.

Comment: actually i am working on dynamic @KafkaListener from couple of days. I am following every post of your and really appreciate your work sir.
thank you.